# I Keep Receiving this error message when i try uploading a csv file that has round about 2000 records

Tags: php, csv, phpmyadmin

```
/*Service Unavailable
        The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
        Additionally, a 503 Service Unavailable error was encountered while trying to use an Error Document to handle the request.
        */
```

I tried  `set_time_limit(0);`
But still doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [guides for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Quite possible your running out of memory, causing php/apache to crash.

Check what its currently set to, then if you have enough resources update it in php.ini

Comment: Good morning i have updated this settings to  
max_input_time -1
memory_limit 512M 
max_execution_time 1800     But the conversion still crushes and the error message still displays

Answer (score 0):

Turn on error_reporting and i think it is the Memory_limit

Comment: Good morning i have updated this settings to  
max_input_time -1
memory_limit 512M 
max_execution_time 1800     But the conversion still crushes and the error message still displays

Comment: Disk /var/tmp (/var/tmp) 96 %                                                                          Disk / (/) 96 %                                                                                                         Should i be worried about any of these

Comment: display_errors (On
error_reporting (~E_ALL)   yes its also on

Answer (score 0):

i seem to have figured out the problem the System was on a shared host Server causing the memory limit to fail